# Fourier Analysis on infinite groups

Tags: group-theory, fourier-analysis

Is there something called  (Fourier Analysis on **infinite** groups)?
I have read some articles in Fourier analysis on finite groups but I wounder if there is such a theory on infinite groups!

Comment: Yes, see Rudin's book [Fourier analysis on groups](http://books.google.com/books?id=k3RNtFSBH8gC), for example. The Wikipedia page on [Pontryagin duality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pontryagin_duality) might be interesting for you.

Comment: @dan : nice link.. thaks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fourier analysis of periodic functions is a way to look at functions on $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ (the circle), an infinite group.  The transform of such a function is a function on $\mathbb{Z}$, another infinite group.  Then you also have the Fourier transform of functions on $\mathbb{R}$, an infinite group.  The transform in this case results in a function on $\mathbb{R}$, an infinite group.  You'd almost suspect that the discrete Fourier transform is the odd one out.  ;-)

And as pointed out by Dan, there is a beautiful theory of Fourier transformations on groups that generalises these examples.

Comment: thanks a lot.. this is very useful :)